How to hex escape unprintable characters in a stream on linux?
I am working on a normal GNU Linux system with standard tools available with coreutils and such. What would be a common simple performant way for converting unprintable sequences in a random stream into hex sequences?
Let's take wtmp binary file. Ideally I would want:
$ dd if=/var/log/wtmp bs=1 count=20 status=none | somecommand
\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

The closest I could come up with is python, but the b' ' still have to be removed. Is there some tool in shell or coreutils that does that and is not python?
 $ dd if=/var/log/wtmp bs=1 count=20 status=none | python -c 'import sys;print(sys.stdin.buffer.read())'
 b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Is there something as simple as cat -v that just generates hex escapes instead of caret sequences?
I am aware of xxd -i and hexdump -e '"%_c"'. Is it possible to maybe make then use \x and escape only unprintable characters?
I tried resaerching, but my google-fu mostly ends in posts about converting hex to ascii in bash, while I want the other way round. I wasn't able to find or come up with a satisfing solution.

Have you tried od?

hi @pmf I read man page, od writes those 00010 headers on the left. Func fact: for me od -w-1 SIGABRTs.

I meant something like od -tx1 -vw1 | sed 's/^[0-7]\+ /\\x/;$d'? You could also add -ta to filter for printable/non-printable characters.

how performant do you need? what size sequence are you processing? for example, on my machine, the pr answer takes ~1min to process 800MB of random data; the perl answer takes ~3min. cat -v completes in 5 seconds

Hi @jhnc I do not need it to be performant or anything. I would want it to be portable, so it works on my friends machine and the 15 years old linux at my company. Perl will work. I have written the question under the assumption that there is something in od or xxd or other common unix tools like pr to make that happen - I am just suprised there is not.

The question specifies performant is desired, and it matters how big the input will be. An algorithm/implementation that is fine for kB may be unusable with GB, if it's even O(n^1.5)

pr from GNU coreutils can do octal:
$ head -c 20 /dev/urandom | pr -tTv
\035EGqlD\321\255\2750\345\227\316T$\225T\360\003H

I don't know one that does hex.

Here is perl version :
perl -pe 's/([[:^print:]])/sprintf("\\x%02x", ord($1))/eg'

